# How to not make a spring boot application die when the method exits

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testng

I am trying to write some integration tests around a Spring Boot application

I do not want to use the SpringJunitRunner that starts the application at every test.This is because I have a lot of tests and I do not want to start the application once for each test. In addition there are some things that are integrated with my company's infrastructure and the second  test always fails while booting up the spring application ( because some other context can be created only once)

So my thought is to use TestNG and boot the application once at the start of the suite and make the tests run against the application and then shut the application down

I am able to boot the application but it dies shortly after the method that boots it exits. Is there a way I can make the application live

I have created a singleton class to manage the application lifecycle

```
  public final class IntegrationTestContext {



    private static IntegrationTestContext INSTANCE = null;

    private Boolean isInitialized = false;

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    SpringApplication app = null;

    public static synchronized IntegrationTestContext getInstance() {

      if (INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = new IntegrationTestContext();      
      }

      return INSTANCE;
    }

    private IntegrationTestContext() {
      if (!isInitialized) {
        runApplication();
        isInitialized = true;
      }
    }

    public ApplicationContext getContext() {
      return applicationContext;
    }



    private PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getBeanFactoryPostProcessor(){    
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.setProperty("some.companyrelated.property.1", "false");
      properties.setProperty("some.companyrelated.property.2", "false");   
      PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pph = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      pph.setProperties(properties);
      return pph;    
    }


    /**
     * This runs the application and sets the spring application context
     * that we can query to get the client beans
     */
    private void runApplication() {    
      try {

        final String[] args = {};
        app = new SpringApplication(Application.class, ClientConfig.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.addInitializers(new MyCompanyInitializer());
        applicationContext = app.run(args);
        applicationContext.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(getBeanFactoryPostProcessor());
        applicationContext.refresh();

      }
      catch (Exception exception) {

      }
    }


    public void shutDownApplication(){    
      try {      
        applicationContext.close();
        isInitialized = false;
        app = null;
        INSTANCE = null;
      }
      catch (Exception e) {      
      }
    }  
  }
```

The issue I am facing is that after the runApplication() method exits the Spring application dies.

What can be done to make this work ? will starting the application in a new process work ?

Comment: try `System.exit(0);` method.

Comment: I am trying to make it not exit ... I figured out that not refreshing the context causes it to die

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed the line that was refreshing the context and it worked